# Do I require a transit visa for Cuba?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, cuba

Does an  Indian citizen holding Indian Passport need any type of visa for Cuba if flying onward within 72 hours to the Cayman Islands?

Comment: Having just come back from Cuba, you will need both a visa (tourist card) and valid travel insurance or you may not be permitted entry.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=KY&EM=RU&TR=CU&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C) you don't need a visa if you have a confirmed ticket and leave within 72 hours:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Visa required, **except for Holders of confirmed onward tickets**

However, according to a Lonely Planet [discussion on the same subject](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/americas-cuba/topics/cuba-transit-visa):

> According to this website you don't need a visa to Cuba when transit is under 72 hours, only have to show airline ticket for next flight.
>
> But don't be to sure that the person in immigration booth know that, since they often are not full trained in the immigration rules, in case problems ask for a supervisor that knows the rules.

So I would suggest contacting a Cuban consulate to get a clarification on the situation since it doesn't seem like transit is a fairly common occurrence in Havana's airport.

Comment: Hi, I am in a similar situation right now. I have a flight from India to Cayman Islands via Havana, Cuba. I will be arriving in Cuba at Terminal 3 and will be departing to Cayman from Terminal 2. As you see that I need to change the terminals in Havan Airport. Do you have any idea if I would be needing a visa for the terminal change?

Answer (score -1):

Passengers in transit are exempt from visa or tourist card requirements if their transit time does not exceed 72 hours. They are allowed to enter Cuba.[1](http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/countryinfo.html)

[Source.](http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/countryinfo.html)
Select:

- Country : Cuba
- Section : Visas
- Subsection : TWOV

Comment: You seem to have left off your source?

Answer (score -2):

A quick Google search says you need a tourist card, and you need it before you get to Cuba. https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=CU&user=EK&subuser=EMIRATES and http://books.google.com/books?id=6X7yAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT1122#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: You have made a mistake here. Cuba is not his _destination_; he is transiting. You entered Cuba as his final destination into Timatic.

Comment: But he's not entering Cuba.

Comment: Besides.  Timatic Link is broken.

Comment: @Karlson Even if you fixed this link (which is trivial) the answer would still be wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHampton More then likely.